# Asynctask Is not Working in demoactivity in gcm

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Code Given Below :

```
private void registerBackground(){

        Toast toast3 = Toast.makeText(context,"-----in regbackground class---------",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast3.show();


     new AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>(){

             @Override
             protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

                String msg = "";

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "---out of try ---"+msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();

                try {
                    if (gcm == null) {
                        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
                  }
                    regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);

                    Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(context, "---regid ---"+regid+"----from background---toast 1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast1.show();

                    msg = "Device registered, registration id=" + regid;

                    Toast toast2 = Toast.makeText(context, "---regid ---"+msg+"----from background---toast 2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast2.show();
                    setRegistrationId(context, regid);


                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    msg = "Error ::" + ex.getMessage();
                    Toast toast4 = Toast.makeText(context,msg+"---error msg",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast4.show();
                }
                return msg;

            }


            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
                mDisplay.append(msg + "\n");
            Toast toast5 = Toast.makeText(context,msg+"---on post execute",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast5.show();
            }
        }.execute(null);



}
```

Here My Whole code . The Problem Is that The Only toast3 is executing After that no Asynctask method executed

Comment: can post erro log here

Comment: Instead you can use `Log`s.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just replace

```
execute(null);
```

with

```
execute(); or execute("url");
```

Comment: i have the problem related to the argument of the AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long>

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using `Toast` in `doInBackground()`... as it runs on background thread. Instead use `Log` to check the values.